# ng-style working intermittently

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using an ng-style to change the background color of a container class (from third party tallinn.css).  The color is loaded from the database.  When I navigate via angular's routing, the ng-style attribute of the container stops working and nothing is loaded into the inline style of the element.  I placed a div inside the container div and set its background color using the same ng-style and scope variable and it works every time.  When I do a hard reload and empty cache, it seems to work everytime.  Here is what chromes debugger shows when it fails:
[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwof8.png)

As you can see, the style tag on the "container" div is empty but the style tag on the inside div is populated with the correct background color rgb(65,87,251).

Code:

```js
//inside angular controller
function setStyles(colors) {
  //set theme styles
  if (colors) {
    $scope.styles = {
      menuBackground: colors.Menu.Background.HexCode // "#4157FB"
    };
  }

}
```

```css
//inside tallinn.css
.navigation .container {
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-style="{'background-color': styles.menuBackground}">
  {{styles.menuBackground}}
  <div ng-style="{'background-color': styles.menuBackground}" style="height:200px; width:200px"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried a couple different methods to get this to work such as using a directive (same problem) then switched to ng-style.

could this be a timing issue with when the css is loading vs when the ng-style should be loading the style from the js?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the color for the 'background-color' is dynamic and loaded from the database.  This is why I'm using ng-style and not hard coding it in the CSS.  ng-style should override the 'background-color' from the CSS shown above (tallinn.css) because it (should) place styles inline.  But it's not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around for it.. The work around is:

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{'backColorMenu': true}">
  {{styles.menuBackground}}
</div>
```

In Css...

```
.backColorMenu{
  background-color:#4157FB;
}
```

Please tell me if this dosent work! Good Luck

**EDIT**

After seeing your comment your hexacolor is not static so you can do it in this format..

controller:

```
$scope.styles = {
background-color: "#4157FB" //May need quotes or not.. Not sure
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-style="styles">
      {{styles.menuBackground}}
    </div>
```

Comment: do you missed to convert it to `ng-class`?

Comment: Sorry my question my not have been clear.  I need to be able to load the background color in from the controller which gets the color from the database.  The color is dynamic based on a theme that is loaded for the page.  So the color can't be static in the CSS.

Comment: I've tried using ng-class instead of ng-style but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry @big_water i ment to use ng-style on my previously edited problem instead of ng-class, can you change it to that and give me results? Thankyou

Comment: using ng-style just brings me back to the original problem of it working only on page refresh.  if I navigate to another page via angular routing then i lose the style from ng-style again on the container element

Comment: I think it's a timing issue somewhere.  Refresh doesn't always fix it but most times it does.  The HTML template that contains the "container" element is loaded by a custom directive that manipulates some CSS in the template as well.

Comment: Then @big_water use the function window.onload(); or $(document).ready(fn)